# Relashionship between Epic and Rquest in VersionONE REST Response

Tags: rest, versionone

I am creating a Tree Table which list the Requests, Epics they contain and then the backlogs, such as this:

Request_1 
|_Epic_1 
  |_Backlog_1 
  |_Backlog_2 ...

The relationship between the Epics and the backlogs and easy because the Backlog data contains the name of the Epic parent (in the answer REST) but I can't find the relationship Request -> Epic. Yet there is a relationship between the Request and the Epics that I can see in the web interface of Version One. Is there a way of finding this relationship?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the metadata showed me that there is an Attribute "Requests" and his reciproque for Request which is "Epics". These attributes are not displayed unless using the selection parameter:

> rootURL/rest-1.v1/Data/Epic?sel=Name,Description,Number,Super.Number,Requests.Number&where=Scope.Name=...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [meta.v1](http://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Endpoints/meta.v1) to learn more about the attributes:

```
<Server Base URI>/meta.v1/Request?xsl=api.xsl
```

Here you will find an attribute called `Epics`. Or

```
<Server Base URI>/meta.v1/Epic?xsl=api.xsl
```

Here you will find the reciprocal called `Requests`.